# How do I model this MySQL table as a Super ColumnFamily in Cassandra?

Tags: mysql, cassandra

I'm currently designing a database for a personal project that I'm working on. Actually, I've already designed it, but now I'm converting it from relational (MySQL) to non-relational (Cassandra).

One of my tables (called "Friend request table") has a primary key that consists of 3 attributes: Receiver ID, Sender ID, and Request time (timestamp). There are 4 other attributes in the table as well:

```
Receiver ID  (Part of primary key)
Sender ID    (Part of primary key)
Request time (Part of primary key)
Request text
Request status
Time last viewed
Time accepted
```

I was thinking of having the rows indexed by the result of appending the sender ID to the receiver ID, and having each super column inside the rows indexed by the request time. That would work for storing the requests, but I don't know how I would go about retrieving them.

Can anyone suggest another way to model this in Cassandra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you think the answer involves supercolumns?  Looks like the most straightforward solution is to model it the same way you would in mysql (with a UUID key) and create indexes on the columns you want to query by.

Comment: I suppose I could divide it in to two regular columnfamilies. Thanks!